# postgres database issues with encoding UTF-8

Tags: postgresql, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1, pg-jdbc

I have created a docker image with this command docker compose up -d
where I was able to load pgAdmin instance in http://localhost:5050/browser/
create a database and table in the same , credentials are working properly.

However when I start to run my main spring boot application **CustomerApplication** it fails with below error >

**org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: la autentificación password falló para el usuario «amigoscode» (pgjdbc: autodetected server-encoding to be ISO-8859-1, if the message is not readable, please check database logs and/or host, port, dbname, user, password, pg_hba.conf)**

I do not know what is wrong, my credentials are correct.
what seems to be the issue?

below are **application.yml** and **docker-compose.yml**

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: amigoscode
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres:
  pgadmin:
```

**application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8080
spring:
  application:
    name: customer
  datasource:
    username: amigoscode
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/customer
    password: password
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        format_sql: true
    show-sql: true
```

**customer table Script**

```
CREATE DATABASE customer
    WITH
    OWNER = amigoscode
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.utf8'
    LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.utf8'
    TABLESPACE = pg_default
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

Comment: Look at the PostgreSQL server log.

Answer (score 3):

Since I have a postgres instance installed and running in my local (port *5432*), the microservice customer was trying to connect to that instance, not the one from docker which was using the same port.

the solution was to change the url port from **application.yml**
url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:**5433**/customer

and the port of postgres from **docker-compose.yml**

**from**

ports:
- "*5432*:5432"

**to**

ports:
- "**5433**:5432"

so microservice connects to the postgres instance in the docker image, not the local one

then re-run docker command docker compose up -d
run the **CustomerApplication** (*SprinbgootApplication*) and this time
application starts up nice and smoothly by creating the customer table.

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was exactly my case. 
Error description was very misleading, I got this error on first try to reconnect to local (docker) right after several windows updates, dbeaver upgrade and odbc updates so I overlooked the obvious fact that remote db connection is open on port 5432

Answer (score 0):

When you created the role `amigoscode` did you actually set a password for it?

```sql
CREATE ROLE amigoscode WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'password';
```

You may have logged into pgadmin as the `postgres` superuser, created the role `amigoscode` and never set a password. The encoding issue looks similar to the one specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496757/wrong-encoding-for-postgresql-messages-in-jdbc) which appears when the supplied password is incorrect. It looks like that pgjdbc bug was fixed in 2014, but has possibly regressed in more modern versions >= 42.2.x as there is currently a [similar unresolved issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496757/wrong-encoding-for-postgresql-messages-in-jdbc).

Other likely alternatives:

- SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD environment variable is set to something else.
- You also have an `application.properties` file which has a different password that will take precedence over the one in `application.yml`.
- You have a different password specified in any of the property sources that spring checks before application.yml (discussion of precedence [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45822571/878272))

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me, the problem is that i was running another instance that was using the port 5432 (postgresql server and docker), I was using dbeaver and it was trying to connect to that instance instead the one that i wanted to use.

Check which applications are using the port and close the ones that you don't need and try again to connect to the database.