# (Problem resolved) The error text is replaced by the Specials symbol

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, intellij-idea

**(Problem resolved)**
sadly that i don't remember what exactly helped. I changed language in whole system, installed postgres, and create new container from new image with postgres

Old question:
I would like to understand what is the problem to solve this, but because the error message is replaced with the specials symbol I can't.

Screenshot:

[image: error message is replaced by Specials symbol]

- The database *customer* exists on server xsakonServer
- Default encoding is set to UTF-8 ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1V2b.png))

here is *application.yml* file:

```
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  application:
    name: customer
  datasource:
    password: password
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/customer
    username: xsakon
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        format_sql: 'true'
    show-sql: 'true'
```

*docker-compose.yml* file:

```
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: xsakon
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped


networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres:
  pgadmin:
```

I already tried replace

```
password: password
username: xsakon
```

to

```
password: 'password'
username: 'xsakon'
```

in *application.yml* file. But result is the same

- Added parameter `-Duser.language=en` to Java VM options
  ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUMyM.png)) applied then restarted project but it didn't help

I hope somebody find out what is the error massage, then I'll fix the problem by myself

Comment: Seeing that your username is cyrillic, I assume the error message is in cyrillic too. This seems to be an issue with your terminal not being set to UTF8.

Comment: Thanks for comment @f1sh I changed default encoding to UTF-8 in setting but result is the same

Comment: Please add the following to the Java VM options: `-Duser.language=en`.

Comment: Thanks for comment @CrazyCoder I think i did what you said(screenshot of it in the end of post) but nothing changed.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/24501509/104891.

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder 2 days ago i somehow fixed this problem, sadly that i don't remember what exactly helped